# Captcha MVC 2.5(Vyacheslav) Refresh Button not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, captcha

in a project I'm working on I have to use Captcha MVC 2.5.
It generally works fine except the Refresh button which doesn't seem to do anything despite me following all the instructions in http://vvson.net/

Here is the complete code of the Partial View:

```
@model CaptchaMvc.Models.DefaultBuildInfoModel
<img id="@Model.ImageElementId" src="@Model.ImageUrl" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"/>
@Html.Hidden(Model.TokenElementId, Model.TokenValue)
<br/>
@{
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    string functionName = string.Format("______{0}________()", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    Model.RefreshButtonText = "Refresh";
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $('#@id').show();
        });


        function @functionName {
            $('#@id').hide();
            $.post("@Model.RefreshUrl", { @Model.TokenParameterName: $('#@Model.TokenElementId').val() },
                function() {
                    $('#@id').show();
                });
            return false;
        }
    </script>

    <a href="#@Model.ImageElementId" id="@id" onclick="@functionName" style="display: flex;">@Model.RefreshButtonText</a>
}

@if (Model.IsRequired)
{
    @Html.TextBox(Model.InputElementId, null, new { data_val = true, data_val_required = Model.RequiredMessage, style = "width:192px" })
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox(Model.InputElementId, null, new { style = "width:192px" })
}
@Html.ValidationMessage(Model.InputElementId)
```

I have also tried @Model.InputElementId in the href of the Refresh button (as in the "instructions") but it doesn't make any difference, plus it seems to me it's trying to refresh the textbox...
The guide in http://vvson.net/ does not help a lot as it is a bit vague so I'm relying on you guys here, hoping someone has used Captcha MVC and has a solution!

Edit: 
Here is what the debugger outputs (using InputElementId)

```
 $(function() {
           $('#38d3e40f39354e5ab959a51ef9da2029').show();
    });


    function ______caf6b1a371bc474bb3c35f5f7705a4c8________() {
        $('#38d3e40f39354e5ab959a51ef9da2029').hide();
        $.post("/ourUI/de/DefaultCaptcha/Refresh", { t: $('#CaptchaDeText').val() },
            function() {

                $('#38d3e40f39354e5ab959a51ef9da2029').show();
                debugger;
            });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Did you add reference to JQuery? Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: Yes JQuery is referenced in the project, we use it everywhere :)
No errors in the console at all, I will edit the initial post to show what the debugger shows!

Comment: Also to add that using the "older method" i.e. @Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter text" , 5, "Is required field.", false) has more or less the same results(only some positioning differences). Captcha image shows up normally, Refresh button doesn't refresh it.

Comment: It is very strange, can you send me a mail (vvs0205_outlook.com replace _ to @) with a project where there is this problem.

Comment: You will get an e-mail soon. Thank you for your time!